# Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist.... I have tried everything

Tags: react-native

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/roam.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/roam.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

I have tried everything. Something to keep in mind is I was even able to make it work in xcode. React-native upgrade, npm install, and killing the port all did not work. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

This is may occurs if you are missing config.h file,

For update config.h file,

1) Close your Xcode.

2) Open Terminal, go to your project's root folder and do:

```
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/
```

3) Run the configure script:

```
./configure
```

4) Open Xcode and try to run your app.

Answer (score 2):

Your are missing some library files in react. So need to add manually in your iOS project.

open xcode project

Go to .xcodeproj :-

1. Download files from
       https://github.com/mmmcompanies/ReactNativeMissingFiles
2. Go to folder iOS
       -> open .xcodeproj
3. Go to folder Libraries -> React.xcodeproj -> ThirdParty folder -> glog
4. update files and run again.

   ```
   you can see missing file config.h and files in glog folder 

   add missing files show in finder and add these files from
   ```

   https://github.com/mmmcompanies/ReactNativeMissingFiles